# Editing an existing make system

Tags: makefile, automake

Which file would I need to edit to add additional files to an existing make system? There are three files:

Makefile.am
Makefile.in
Makefile

They all contain information about the sources that are being used. I assume it is the Makefile.am, becaue in Makefile.in it says "generated by automake". My question is though: How can I tell the system to regenerate Makefiles with my changes, but without changing anything else?

Comment: You appear to be using automake. I don't really know automake, but I think you should edit `Makefile.am`. Automake will read that and generate `Makefile.in`, configure will read that and generate `Makefile`, Make will read that and build things. I'll add the `automake`tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your modifications to `Makefile.am`, and run `make`.  This should trigger a call to `automake` (to regenerate `Makefile.in`) and then to `configure` to regenerated `Makefile`.

In some projects these rebuild rules are disabled and nothing will happen. In that case you have to run `./configure --enable-maintainer-mode` first to enabled these.